# How do we show that $N(a + bω) = a^2 − ab + b^2 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

We are given

> Let  $\omega $ be defined as  $\left(\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} = \frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right).$

subset $ A \subseteq \mathbb{C} $ consisting of all elements of the form $ a + b \omega$, with $ a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$,

Define a function $N ∶ A →\mathbb R$ by $N(u) =\lVert u\rVert^2$
(the square of the
complex norm).

Show that
$N(a + bω) = a^2 − ab + b^2.$

I don't get how $N(u)$ isn't just equal to $a^2 + b^2 + b^2\omega$.

I got that by $(a + b\omega)(a - b\omega) = a^2 -b^2\omega^2$
where we know $\omega^2 = -1 - \omega$ thus giving us $a^2 +b^2 +b^2\omega$

I used this definition provided to me for complex norm:

There is a function $N : \mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$ defined by
$N(a + bi) := (a + bi)(a − bi) = a^2 + b^2 = ||a + bi||^2$
This is called a norm function.

Comment: Hint: $|z|^2=z\bar z$

Comment: Hint: $(a + b \omega)(a + b \overline\omega) = \ldots$

Comment: Btw, how do *you* get $a^2-b^2$? Please answer by editing your post, rather than in a comment.

Comment: okay but doesnt that just factor out to $a^2+ b^2$ + bω

Comment: No.____________

Comment: hi sorry edited it out to what I'm getting instead of $a^2 - b^2$

Comment: Please insert the details of your calculation, so that we can locate your mistake.

Comment: It looks like you assumed that $\overline\omega=-\omega$, which is not true.  Instead, $\overline\omega=\omega^2$

Comment: May be you mixed with $\overline{e^{it}}=e^{-it}.$

Comment: if i did do that wouldnt that contradict what the definition provided to me says

Comment: $\omega$ has a real part and an imaginary part.  Switch only the sign of the imaginary part to get the conjugate

Comment: ohhh wait gimme a bit to try that

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent so long on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> I don't get how $N(u)$ isn't just equal to $a^2 + b^2 + b^2\omega$

> I got that by $(a + b\omega)(a - b\omega) = a^2 -b^2\omega^2$
> where we know $\omega^2 = -1 - \omega$ thus giving us $a^2 +b^2 +b^2\omega$

Your mistake was that you assumed that $\overline\omega=-\omega$, which is not true.

$\omega$ has a real part and an imaginary part.

Switch only the sign of the imaginary part to get the complex conjugate.

Can you show that in fact $\overline\omega=\omega^2$?

Can you then apply $\omega^2=-1-\omega$ to show that $(a+b\omega)(a+b\overline\omega)=a^2+b^2-ab$?

Comment: It is true that $\overline i=-i$, but it is not true that $\overline \omega=-\omega$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}|a + b\omega|^2&=(a + b\omega)(a + b\bar\omega)\\&=a^2+ab(\omega+\bar\omega)+b^2\omega\bar\omega\\&=a^2+2ab\operatorname{Re}(\omega)+b^2|\omega|^2\\&=a^2-ab+b^2.
\end{align}$$